# Does ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor's cancel() method cancel all tasks in work queue?

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice, threadpoolexecutor, scheduledexecutorservice

In essence, does calling the `cancel()` method in the `ScheduledFuture<>` returned by the `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.scheduleAtFixedRate` cancel *all* the future executions that may be queued in the ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor's work queue? Does the returned `ScheduledFuture` represent all possible future executions of that task? Or does it simply cancel the next scheduled execution, but may execute another execution immediately after?

Comment: What is not clear about the Javadoc?  [It cancels that one specific task](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#cancel(boolean))

Comment: I guess my confusion here stems from the fact that the definition of what a "task" is is  defined loosely when it comes to Future and ScheduledFuture. In Future, it's clear that it is the result of a single callable, whereas for a ScheduledFuture used in context of scheduleAtFixedRate, the "task" is not a single execution, but rather all the executions that are currently executing or have been scheduled for execution

Comment: If we assume the definition from [Future](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#cancel(boolean)) as is, that would imply that a single execution of a scheduled task would return a future that defines the result of that scheduled task - which clearly doesn't seem like the case in practice, hence my original question

Comment: The answer is in the Javadoc for [scheduleAtFixedRate()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html#scheduleAtFixedRate(java.lang.Runnable,long,long,java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)).  Cancelling the future seems to be one of the exceptional conditions that cancels all future executions.

Answer (score 1):

> does calling the cancel() method in the ScheduledFuture<> returned by the ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.scheduleAtFixedRate cancel all the future executions that may be queued in the ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor's work queue?

I think this is a great question given that you're asking about this in the context of a `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor`. The [ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html) docs indicate that when a task is cancelled, it may not be automatically removed from the queue, read the following.

> When a submitted task is cancelled before it is run, execution is suppressed. By default, such a cancelled task is not automatically removed from the work queue until its delay elapses. While this enables further inspection and monitoring, it may also cause unbounded retention of cancelled tasks. To avoid this, set setRemoveOnCancelPolicy(boolean) to true, which causes tasks to be immediately removed from the work queue at time of cancellation.